# Problema para inicializar mi proyecto laravel

Tags: laravel, composer, artisan

tengo mi proyecto en laravel y de pronto ya no funciona los comandos de artisan. Cuando hago un `php artisan serve` me dice el siguiente error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /home/asd/Documentos/proyectos/plantilla_proyectos/bootstrap/app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /home/asd/Documentos/proyectos/plantilla_proyectos/artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/asd/Documentos/proyectos/plantilla_proyectos/bootstrap/app.php on line 14
```

Como si no me detectara cosas tan basicas como la clase **'Illuminate\Foundation\Application'**, no se porque, he probado los compandos `composer install`, `composer update`,  `php artisan key:generate`, etc.. los de composer los ejecuta (pero no arregla nada) y los de artisan directamente petan todos. No se porque ha pasado esto la verdad. Alguien sabe que puede estar provocando estos problemas ?

Aclaro que el proyecto ya lleva un desarrollo detras y no es nuevo. Por tanto la opcion de crear un nuevo proyecto no esta entre las posibles opciones.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con `composer dump-autoload` y `composer update --no-scripts`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Para que omita la ejecución de los scripts en el **composer.json**